# How can I connect multiple iPhone screens to make a larger display?

Tags: ios, iphone, mosaic

I want to connect multiple iPhone/iPad display to have a larger display. This large display will be able to display a single photo or video in that screen. Mosaic app is doing so and is on the app store. They also provide SDK for the same. Here is the link for that SDK - http://www.mosaic.io/sdk. Can anyone help me out with this? Is there any SDK available which can fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Any SDK other than Mosaic? Doesn't that solve your needs?

Comment: Their app is not working. I haven't tried their SDK. I am looking into it. Have you ever used the SDK by Mosaic?

Comment: No, I haven't but I think you should contact them and ask them about the compilation errors in their app.

Comment: Didi that already. Thanks for your time. :)